# How can I get one response for different API pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get one response from an API that has different pages URL, how can i achieve this in just one API call.

Here's my code

```
async function arrayFetcher (){
      // Get `urlArray` from object param
      let urlArray = [];
      let url = ""
      for(let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
          url = `https://api.google.com/page=250&page=${i}&sparkline=false`
      }
      const resp =  await axios.get(url)
      const response = await urlArray?.Promise?.all(resp).then(res => res.json());
      console.log(response)
  };
```

Comment: You're changing `url` 20 times?

Comment: I think for loop is only changing the url. Your final url would be 19. There is no way in plain react you can get information from 20 pages in only one call I think. (maybe there is a npm library that does that but not aware of any). Include the axios call inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all`. Make an array (let's say `urls`) & then -

```
const results = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
  const resp = await axios.get(url);
  return resp.json();
}));
```

Update: You also need to push the url into the `urlArray`

```
for(let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    url = `https://api.google.com/page=250&page=${i}&sparkline=false`;
    urlArray.push(url);
}
```

Then use it in `Promise.all`.

Comment: tried it but am getting resp.json() is not a function

Comment: You also need to push the `url` into the `urlArray`. In your code `urlArray` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Promise.all , an example could be:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const url1 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    const url2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2'
    const url3 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3'

    const result = await Promise.all([fetch(url1), fetch(url2), fetch(url3)])
    const dataArr = result.map(result => result.json())
    const allData = Promise.all(dataArr)
    return allData
}


fetchData().then(res => console.log(res))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gkhmcbp/

Answer (score 0):

This won't result in one API call, rather the network will see one call per URL which is called by `axios.get(url)`. To make one API call and get the same data would require additional parameters on the endpoint or a new endpoint; this is a server side change by the API owner.

Axios does not require `response.json()` as it already does that for you. The browser native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) does require it, `fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`.

```js
async function arrayFetcher() {
  // generate 5 urls to fetch
  // API starts at 1 but index at 0, so `index+1` for valid URI
  const urls = [...Array(5).keys()].map((item, index) => `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index+1}`);

  // make API calls
  const results = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => await axios.get(url)));

  // display each result
  // Axios places the value in `data` property
  results.forEach(result => console.log(result.data));
}

arrayFetcher();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

You could potentially improve this code to separate the array generation from the fetcher function and pass in the array as an argument. Example:

```js
async function arrayFetcher(urls) { /*...*/ }

function generateUrlArray(baseUrl, amount) {
  return [...Array(amount).keys()].map((item, index) => `${baseUrl}${index+1}`);
}

const urls = generateUrlArray('https://example.com/', 5); // generate array

arrayFetcher(urls);
```